# How to check if multiple vars contain the same word? - Batch

Tags: batch-file

If I have multiple vars...
Say

```
%v1%  
%v2%  
%v3%
```

And I want to check if all vars contain a specific word. If all variables DO in fact have that word, execute a
    goto and vise-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "checkfor=someword"
FOR %%a IN (word1 word2 word3) DO SET "%%a=%checkfor%"
SET "word4=anotherword"
CALL :check
CALL :check2
ECHO ================
SET "word4=%checkfor%"
CALL :check
CALL :check2
ECHO ================
SET "word3="
CALL :check
CALL :check2
ECHO ================
GOTO :EOF

:: Check that all contain "someword"
:check
SET word
FOR %%a IN (word1 word2 word3 word4) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set 2^>nul') DO IF /i "%%a"=="%%b" IF /i "%%c" neq "%checkfor%" GOTO notsame1
)
ECHO all vars contain "%checkfor%"
GOTO :eof
:notsame1
ECHO NOT all vars contain "%checkfor%"
GOTO :eof

:: Check that all contain "someword"
:check2
FOR %%a IN (word1 word2 word3 word4) DO (
 SET "$found="
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set 2^>nul') DO IF /i "%%a"=="%%b" SET "$found=Y"&IF /i "%%c" neq "%checkfor%" GOTO notsame2
 IF NOT DEFINED $found GOTO notsame2
)
ECHO all vars contain "%checkfor%"
GOTO :eof
:notsame2
ECHO NOT all vars contain "%checkfor%"
GOTO :eof
```

Two methods here.

The first checks that the variables are(not) the same **if they are defined**. The second checks that they are **all defined and all identical to the target**

natrally, you could use

```
set "myvars=word1 word2 word3 word4"
```

then use

```
FOR %%a IN (%myvars%) DO (
```

if that's more convenient (which it probably would be, if this check is set as a subroutine)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal
rem word to check for
set word=word

rem variables
set var1=word1
rem set var=now0rd
set var2=word2
set var3=word3

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set checker=yes
rem list all your variables here
for %%a in  (var1 var2 var3 var) do (
    if defined %%a (
        set tmpvar=!%%a!
        rem echo "!tmpvar:%word%=!" NEQ "!tmpvar!"
        if "!tmpvar:%word%=!" EQU "!tmpvar!" (
            set checker=no
        )
    )

)
endlocal && (
    set checker=%checker%
)

rem remove the REMs to activate goto
if %checker% EQU yes (
    echo all variables contain %word%
    rem goto :somewhere
) else (
    echo at least one variable does not contain %word%
    rem goto :somewhere_else
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Excuse me. The `if defined %%a (` and `set tmpvar=!%%a!` parts may be omitted. You may directly use `if "!%%a:%word%=!" EQU "!%%a!" (` although it looks pretty weird! **:)**

Comment: @Aacini - absolutely right.But do not always have a time to optimize my answers here :)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem The values
    set "v1=this is a test"
    set "v2=a test this is"
    set "v3=this a test is"
    set "v4=this is a toast"

    rem What to search and where to search
    set "word=test"
    set "vars="v1" "v2" "v3" "v4""

    rem Count the number of variables
    set "numberOfVars=0"
    for %%a in (%vars%) do set /a "numberOfVars+=1"

    rem Count the number of variables containing the searched word
    set "occurences=0"
    for /f %%a in ('
        cmd /q /v /c "for %%a in (%vars%) do echo(!%%~a!" 
        ^| find /c "%word%"
    ') do set "occurrences=%%a"

    if %numberOfVars% equ %occurrences% (
        echo match 
    ) else (
        echo no match 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the search word can only appear **one time** in each variable, then the method below is the fastest way to solve this problem because it is *not* based on an iterative for with each variable, but in an expression that is evaluated just once no matter the number of variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion



rem Define variables
set "v1=this is a test"
set "v2=a test this is"
set "v3=this a test is"
set "v4=this is a toast"

rem Define variables to search
set "vars=v1 v2 v3 v4"

rem Define a character that does NOT appear in the variables
set "delimiter=|"



rem Count the number of variables plus one
set tokens=1
for %%a in (%vars%) do set /A tokens+=1

rem Assemble the search expression
set "expr= ^!%vars: =^! ^!%^! "



rem Example: search for word "test"
set "word=test"
set "values=%expr%"
for /F "tokens=%tokens% delims=%delimiter%" %%a in ("!values:%word%=%delimiter%!") do (
   echo The word %word% is in all variables
   goto nextTest1
)
echo The word %word% is NOT in all variables...

:nextTest1
rem Example: search for word "this"
set "word=this"
set "values=%expr%"
for /F "tokens=%tokens% delims=%delimiter%" %%a in ("!values:%word%=%delimiter%!") do (
   echo The word %word% is in all variables
   goto nextTest2
)
echo The word %word% is NOT in all variables...

:nextTest2
rem Example: modify v4 and search again for "test"
set "v4=this finally also was a test"
set "word=test"
set "values=%expr%"
for /F "tokens=%tokens% delims=%delimiter%" %%a in ("!values:%word%=%delimiter%!") do (
   echo The word %word% is in all variables
   goto :EOF
)
echo The word %word% is NOT in all variables...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the "each variable contains a string" interpretation,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "Word1=Magic Sword"
SET "Word2=Magic Boots"
SET "Word3=Book of Magic Spells"
SET "Word4=Magic Underwear"

CALL :checkfor "Magic" "word1 word2 word3 word4"
ECHO =============================================
SET "Word3=Boring Book of Eggplant Recipes"

CALL :checkfor "Magic" "word1 word2 word3 word4"
ECHO =============================================

SET "Word3="

CALL :checkfor "Magic" "word1 word2 word3 word4"
ECHO =============================================

GOTO :EOF

:: Check that "%1" appears in each variable "%2"
:checkfor
ECHO check FOR "%~1" IN %~2
SET word

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "vars= %~2 "

FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set^|findstr /c:"%~1"') DO SET "vars=!vars: %%a = !
IF "%vars: =%"=="" ECHO "%~1" found IN each of "%~2"&GOTO :EOF 
FOR %%a IN (%vars%) DO IF DEFINED %%a ECHO "%~1" NOT found IN "%%a"&GOTO :EOF
ECHO all vars contain "%~1" but %vars% undefined
GOTO :eof
```